# List [rows] within range of plus or minus the average of a column

Tags: mysql

I am doing a homework problem: "List each of the clients’ name and weight, for those clients who within 10 pounds of the average weight. (Do NOT use [an integer] as the average weight, you will have to use a function to find the average weight.)

I have tried several things like: `"WHERE c_weight BETWEEN avg(c_weight - 10) and avg(c_weight + 10)"` to no avail.

My current code compiles:

```
SELECT c_first, c_last, c_weight
FROM client
WHERE c_weight between 160 and 180;
```

The code above is just a placeholder; I know correction lies in my `WHERE` statement, I'm just not sure how to properly create it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this as:

```
SELECT c_first, c_last, c_weight
FROM client
WHERE c_weight - (SELECT AVG(c_weight) FROM client) BETWEEN -10 AND 10;
```

Note that we use a subquery to find the average weight across the entire table, and then compare each record's weight against that to see if it be within range.

To understand the logic in the `WHERE` clause, let's that the average weight were 150.  Then the range in the `WHERE` clause is saying:

```
c_weight - 150 >= -10 AND c_weight - 150 <= 10
```

This is identical to saying:

```
c_weight >= 140 AND c_weight <= 160
```

Comment: can you explain the WHERE statement? Like, type it as you would say it out loud? This worked (thanks a lot!) but I dont understand how. weight MINUS (AVERAGE weight) between -10 and 10 computes to plus or minus average weight.

Comment: @Craze Check the updated answer for an explanation with sample numbers.